Multiple OpenAPI entry point for one API Platform
Is there any way to create multiple OpenAPI docs entry point in one application?
Currently the base url for the OpenAPI (formerly swagger) is /api/docs. What if I would like to create a secondary in the same app: /api/docs-customer?
For example: I would create

one for developers and administrators
and one for customers

I have tried to get information from github issues and the documentation. And obviously from my best friends: the Google, Qwant and so on.
